# How to record video in Xamarin forms without using plugins?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to create own camera custom controls (I need to add my own buttons for recording) for video recording in Xamarin forms?. How do I achieve this without using any media plugin?

Comment: you will have to write your own platform specific code and expose it via DI or custom renderers

Comment: @Jason, Can you provide any online link for that or sample code?

Comment: this is exactly how the media plugin works - look at the source code for that

Comment: @Jason, Okay. Thank you